# How to loop parameter value in Jenkins Declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline where I need to get the parameter value as Integer and do for loop.

Say for example: If the value of the parameter is : 3, I want loop the code 3 times. Below is what I tried but could not find the exact solution

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('loop'){
            steps {
                echo "Looping"
            script {
            for (int i=0; i<=params.count;i++) {
                echo "$i"
            }
            }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pipeline script should provide you hint:

```java
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('loop'){
            steps {
                echo "Looping"
            script {
                int num = "${env.count}".toInteger()
                
            for (int i=0; i<= num; ++i) {
                echo "Hello"
            }
            }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In above pipeline script, I have used variable `count` to accept from user the number of times the script needs to run. I have used `This project is parameterised` (below is the screenshot)

[image]

Now, i used `toInterger()` to convert the string value to int and then iterate it using `for` loop.

Below is the output when the value of `count = 3`

[image]

Comment: Happy to help :)